# How to get found substring while using Regex.Replace method?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using this code to replace all found values in string by indexes:

```
int i = 0;
input = "FGS1=(B+A*10)+A*10+(C*10.5)";
Regex r = new Regex("([A-Z][A-Z\\d]*)");
bool f = false;
MatchEvaluator me = delegate(Match m)
{
  f = true;
  i++;
  return "i" + i.ToString();
};
do { f = false; input = r.Replace(input, me); } while (f);
//expected result: input == "i1=(i2+i3*10)+i4*10+(i5*10.5)"
```

But i have to do it in more complex way, for what i have to do something with found value. For example:

```
MatchEvaluator me = delegate(Match m)
{
  foundValue = /*getting value*/;
  if (foundValue = "A") i--;
  f = true;
  i++;
  return "i" + i.ToString();
};
```

Expected result for this code: `"i1=(i2+i2*10)+i2*10+(i3*10.5)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you need to implement a variable assignment in which you assign ix (where x is an incrementing number) to each variable and then reuse this value if it appears, we can write the following code to solve your problem:

```
var identifiers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
int i = 0;
var input = "FGS1=(B+A*10)+A*10+(C*10.5)";
Regex r = new Regex("([A-Z][A-Z\\d]*)");
bool f = false;

MatchEvaluator me = delegate(Match m)
{
    var variableName = m.ToString();

    if(identifiers.ContainsKey(variableName)){
        return identifiers[variableName];
    }
    else {
        i++;
        var newVariableName = "i" + i.ToString();
        identifiers[variableName] = newVariableName;
        return newVariableName;
    }
};

input = r.Replace(input, me);
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

This code should print:
i1=(i2+i3*10)+i3*10+(i4*10.5)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Groups` collection in the match object to get the matched groups. The first item is the entire match, so the value from the first group is at index 1:

```
string foundValue = m.Groups[1].Value;
if (foundValue == "A") i--;
```

Comment: In some reason my code loops with this, but more looks like it's originally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be answered by Guffa already, just want to share my alternative way to solve your problem, using more feature from .NET Regex (If I understand your problem correctly):

```
int i = 1;
string input = "FGS1=(B+A*10)+A*10+(C*10.5)";   
var lookUp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var output = Regex.Replace(input, 
             "([A-Z][A-Z\\d]*)", 
             m => { 
                if(!lookUp.ContainsKey(m.Value))
                {           
                    lookUp[m.Value] = "i" + i++;            
                }
                return lookUp[m.Value]; 
            });
Console.WriteLine(output);      //i1=(i2+i3*10)+i3*10+(i4*10.5)
```

I use a dictionary to keep track of which matched is repeated

This should work even if your repeated matched is different from "A". In your original solution, it checks specifically for "A", which is quite fragile

Comment: Looks great. But looks like previous answer do exactly same, but in  bit more obvious way to me. This way would be better if i had more time to propperly understand .NET. Thank you, anyway.